# Apache Tomcat is not responding - Unsupported target VM

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat10

I have java 11 project and using Apache Tomcat 10.

```
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode)

Server version: Apache Tomcat/10.1.10
Server built:   Jun 2 2023 18:11:59 UTC
Server number:  10.1.10.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.4.17-2136.312.3.4.el8uek.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    11.0.19+7-LTS
JVM Vendor:     Amazon.com Inc.
```

my gui is not responding and according to the catalina log:

```
Aug 21, 2023 5:07:20 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler generateClass
WARNING: Unsupported source VM [11] requested, using [1.3]
Aug 21, 2023 5:07:20 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler generateClass
WARNING: Unsupported target VM [11] requested, using [1.2]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: *my gui is not responding and according to the catalina log:* in a web app that you've deployed or are you talking about Tomcat with *nothing* deployed?

Comment: in a web app that we deployed

Comment: I'm just making an educated guess that it contains an ancient (15 years?) version of the jasper compiler. I think it should be tomcat-jasper these days, not jasper-compiler-jdt, which you might have

Comment: Can you describe the project better?  As @g00se says, it *appears* that you've got one or more prehistoric Java runtimes on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was :
edit the web.xml

and add to the jsp servlet:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
```